# MongoDB / Mongoose - Importing numbers with commas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js, mongoose-schema

I am working on an app which (amongst other things) allows CSV upload, converts that into JSON and then imports the JSON into mongo.

I have a schema which looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var statementSchema = new Schema({
 date : {type:Date, required:true},
 name: {type:String, required:true},
 method: {type:String},
 amount: {type:Number, required:true},
 category: {type:String, default:'Not Set'},
 importDate: {type : Date, default:Date.now, required:true}
});

statementSchema.index({"date":1, "name":1, "amount":1}, {unique: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Statement', statementSchema);
```

I have an import script which loops through a JSON object and persists according to the schema:

```
 for( var i = 0; i < statements.length; i++ ) {
.....
var newStatement = new Statement();
//the amount value is a string currently
newStatement.amount = Number(statements[i].amount);
...
}
```

However as I say any objects that have an amount that includes a comma e.g. `1,120.55` do not get persisted.

I have tried mongoose-currency which resolves the issue but then I end up with a value such as 112055.  The docs say to use `.toFixed(2)` when showing to users but I am running a `.find()` query in my route which is then passed to Handlebars to render.

I've tried various handlebars functions

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('amountFixed', function(amount) {
  return amount.toFixed(2);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('amountCurrency', function(amount) {
  return amount.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
});
```

(as well as format.js and handlebars.numeral) to try to correct the formatting but I can't quite get it right.

So my question is - what is the best way of importing a value with a comma into mongo and then showing it to a user?

Comment: One option would be to just use `String` instead of `Number` to store those values, unless you need the actual numerical value, in which case `mongoose-currency` would make sense (and use `(amount / 100).toString().replace(/.../)` for formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some experimenting and saw that:

```
parseFloat("1,120.55"); // 1
parseInt("1,120.55"); // 1
```

So the easiest point that I see is to cleanup the `,` with a replace function

```
newStatement.amount = Number(statements[i].amount.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

And this should do the trick.
And after you will need to create a formating helper to display back the commas.

Comment: Thanks - I need to keep the type as `Number` so I'll go with that and add the comma back in on the way out if needed.